# How to stop TinyMCE removing <p> inside <td>

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

I'm currently suffering from TinyMCE (v=3.5.8) removing html from a customer's CMS-installation. In old versions there was cleanup:false and cleanup_on_startup but 3.4+ those are deprecated. However, I struggle to fix the behaviour. First off the code it is messing with:

**Before:**

```
<td><p align="center">
  <strong><span style="color: #336600; font-family: georgia,times new roman,times,serif; font-size: x-large;">
    Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text
  </span></strong>
</p></td>
```

**After clicking into table cell**

```
<td>
  <strong><span style="color: #336600; font-family: georgia,times new roman,times,serif; font-size: x-large;">
    Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text
  </span></strong>
</td>
```

So the question is, why doesn't the following init-params stop the behaviour?

```
// Skin options
skin : "o2k7",
skin_variant : "silver",

// custom params from attribute tinyparams
verify_html:false, 
fix_table_elements:false,
schema:"html4",
valid_children: "+body[style],+td[p],+tr[p],+th[p],+tbody[p],+table[p]"
```

From my understanding, it is the process of validating children rules that removes my Paragraph-Tag. I was also using valid_elements with the full xhtml ruleset mentioned here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:valid_elements

Anybody got a clue what is going on here? I would be thankfull for any hints.

Answer (score -1):

Set the below option so that it doesn't check your HTML for errors.

```
verify_html : false
```